# ruby array with arrays how to get the array number when iterating over each of them and searching by number

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

if I get from params something like a 165. and this is number contains in array number 3 of 9.
how to get this number of the array?

```
range = 50..450
cutter = range.last/50
b = range.each_slice(range.last/cutter).to_a

b #=> [[50, 51,..., 99],..., [400, 401,..., 450]]
```

How to get it?

Comment: In your code, the variable `a` is undefined. Also, i don't understand what `b` is supposed to represent, since the expression `[[50..99]..[400..450]]` is not valid Ruby (the lower/upper bound of a range can't be an array).

Comment: @user1934428 sorry, i updated. b in my example return array of 9 arrays. each array have a 50 numbers,

Comment: Even after the update, the two problems I mentioned in my comment are still there ...... Did you ever actually **execute** the code you posted? Please write a complete example, which we can reproduce in `irb`, describe the output you receive, and the output you would like to see.

Comment: @user1934428 yep. try it again.

Comment: Your code produces the array `b #=> [[50, 51,..., 99],..., [400, 401,..., 449], [450]]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The array method you want is [`find_index`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Array.html#method-i-find_index). I think this will do what you want:

```
b.find_index {|a| a.include?(165)}
```

Comment: @CarySwoveland I think you are wrong. I've just tried it and get `NoMethodError (undefined method 'include?' for 50:Integer)`. `find_index` iterates over the outer arrays in the block, so `a` is always one of the inner arrays.